# PHP Display username of people from a database that have uploaded a file

Tags: php, html

I'm fairly new to php so please don't roast me :)

My current code only shows the current logged in user and their work with session management 
however I want to display all users from my database (member) who have uploaded their work and have a hyperlink at the bottom of the page so people can click on their name and view all the pictures they have uploaded. ( << not to sure how to do that ).  Is there a way to show only users that have uploaded a file to the database and not just registered users?

```php
<?php
  session_start();
  $page_title="Gallery Home";
  include("header.inc");
  include("nav.inc");
  include("categorys.inc");
?>
    <!-- start of main content -->
    <div id="main-content">
<?php 

  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "artworks")  or die(mysqli_error($db));
  $q = "select * from artwork";

  $results = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results))
  {

    print "<a href='artwork.php?artwork_id={$row['artwork_id']}'</a><img src='uploads/{$row['filename']}'height= '300' width='333.33' >";

   }

?>
     </div>

     <!-- end of main content -->
<?php

  //gets username of current user 
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  //this is the link that shows all pictures uploaded by user  
  print "<td><a href='member.php?$username='$username'>$username</a></td>\n";
?>


<?php 
  include("footer.inc");
?>
```

Thanks Heaps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps :) Goodluck!

```
<!-- start of main content -->
<div id="main-content">
<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","artworks");
$q = "SELECT * FROM artwork GROUP BY member_id";  //artwork table must have member id, this id will be used matching for table member member id
$results = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){ //if there is file/member id from table artwork matched for table member member id
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $member_id1 = $row['member_id'];    

        $query_member = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$member_id1' ")or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //only display member that has uploaded file
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($query_member);
        $member_id = $res['id']; //this will be use for displaying uploaded file
        $member_username = $res['username'];
    ?>
        <a href="member.php?member_id=<?php echo $member_id; ?>" target="_blank" ><?php echo $member_username; ?></a><br> <!--  -->
    <?php
    }
}
else{
    echo "No Result Found.";    
}
?>
 </div>
 <!-- end of main content -->
```

This will be the member.php

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","artworks");
$member_id = $_GET['member_id'];
$query_artwork = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE member_id='$member_id' ")or die(mysqli_error($db));
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_artwork) > 0){
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query_artwork)){
    $filename = $res['filename'];
    ?>
    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $filename; ?>" height= "300px" width="333.33px" >
    <?php
}
}
else{   
echo "No artworks found.";
}
?>
```